Appwrite : Having problem signing out the user
All the methods in appwrite (GET, POST, etc) are working but the DELETE request is giving a CORS error while signing out.
I have set localhost as project host in the appwrite as well.

Here is my code:
async logout(){
        try {
            const account = await this.account.deleteSessions()
            return account
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite :: logout :: ", error);
            throw error
        }
    }


Please try the following

Add as platform via Appwrite Console
Clear browser cache or try private tab
Create new project and try sames in this project

